# Show Button in Admin ListView - Upgrade to Django 4

Tags: django, django-admin

I have upgraded to django 4.2.2. from 1.X. In my listview I have buttons for every element, the button contains a link. Everything worked well but after upgrading the quotes are rendered as '&quot' in html instead of '"'.

```
def clone_button(self,obj):
    button = "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"location.href='/admin/clone/%s/%s'\";>Clone</button>" % (obj.id,"keep_date")
    return button
clone_button.allow_tags=True
```

What do I have to do differently now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the html [string as safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) for output. Or use the [html_output](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) shortcut.